# Is there a way I can log error and redirect from ASP.Net Core Exception middleware with Ajax request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I currently have a global exception middleware in my ASP.Net Core MVC App, this works well when making a non-ajax request but does not work when an Ajax request is made and exception occurs.

My question - Is there a way I can also log an error and redirect to a custom error page when an Ajax request is made? Below is my middleware code.

```
public class AppExceptionMiddleware: IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var _service = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserAccountService>();

        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {

            //Log Error to db
            var routeData = context.GetRouteData();

            var controllerName = routeData?.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = routeData?.Values["action"];
            var areaName = routeData?.Values["area"];


            _service.LogAppException(new Application.ViewModels.ErrorLogModel
            {
                errorMessage = error.Message,
                errorSource = error.Source,
                errorXML = error.ToString(),
                errorType = error.GetType().Name,
                controllerName = controllerName == null ? "Unknown" : controllerName.ToString(),
                actionName = actionName == null ? "Unknown" : actionName.ToString(),
                areaName = areaName == null ? " " : areaName.ToString(),

            });

            context.Response.Redirect(("/error/oops"));
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 1):

> My question - Is there a way I can also log an error and redirect to a
> custom error page when an Ajax request is made?

Actually, we cannot because, when submitting ajax request which always expect a response and execute either of success or error and the redirect to other page won't executed because ajax request would always ended up with expecting response from the method you have submitted request to.

In other words, Redirection will not act accordingly in case of ajax request. Altough we can trace ajax request from the middleware by checking its request header whether its an ajax request.

However, `await next(context);` will move to next context and that's th controller action where your ajax request must return a response, thus the redirection won't work.

Let's take a look in practice:

Middleware:

```
                var checkRequest = context.Request;

                var isAjax = checkRequest.IsAjaxRequest();
                if (isAjax)
                {
                    var redirectToDesiredURL = "http://localhost:5094/Home/Index";//URL you want to redirect

                    context.Response.Redirect(redirectToDesiredURL);
                }
                await next(context);
```

**Note:** In ajax request scenario, you would need to handle it from client side within ajax succeess or error function. On top of this,  If any error encountered in backend, furthermore, you can send response message or code and finally, based on that you can check the response and if you got error then you can redirect to anywhere by using `window.location.href`. This is the way.

Ouput:

[image]

**Note:** But in non-ajax context request doesn't always return back to the caller or client thus, we can redirect to other page.